# MVC C# to Json correct way to format url in string array?

Tags: json, c#-4.0

I'm trying to understand correct way to handle backslashes in urls within a string array that are returned via Json...I have commented the goal below

> ```
>    public JsonResult PhotosByListingId(int id)
>     {
>        var pics =  _listingRepository.GetById(id).ListingPhoto.ToList();
> ```

```
       List<string> l = new List<string>();

        foreach(var p in pics)
        {
            //l.Add("albums\\/album1\\/" + p.PhotoName);   //nope
            //l.Add(@"albums\/album1\/" + p.PhotoName);  //nope
            l.Add("albums/album1/" + p.PhotoName); //????? nope
        }

        string[] s = l.ToArray();

        return Json(s, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        //needs to be this..THE GOAL
        //  ["albums\/album1\/10k.jpg","albums\/album1\/10l.jpg","albums\/album1\/10y.jpg"]


        //but is returning this?
        // ["albums/album1/10k.jpg","albums/album1/10l.jpg","albums/album1/10y.jpg"]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try string.Replace:

```
   public JsonResult PhotosByListingId(int id)
{
   var pics =  _listingRepository.GetById(id).ListingPhoto.ToList();
   List<string> l = new List<string>();

    foreach(var p in pics)
    {
        l.Add("albums/album1/".Replace("/", "\\/") + p.PhotoName);
    }

    string[] s = l.ToArray();

    return Json(s, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Because the javascript serialiser is converting the slashes, you could implement serialisation yourself and modify the generated JSON:

```
        public string CustomSerialised()
    {
        string test = "/This/That/The other/";
        List<string> arr = new List<string>();
        arr.Add(test);
        arr.Add(test);
        arr.Add(test);

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        return s.Serialize(arr).Replace("/","\\/");
    }
```

This can be navigated to using the standard routing pattern when used within a controller.

Comment: Hi Oliver, Thanks for your suggestion that's close..but that also isn't it....that returns ;["albums\\/album1\\/10k.jpg","albums\\/album1\\/10l.jpg","albums\\/album1\\/10y.jpg"]

Comment: How come you want it to return \/?

Comment: I have a jquery plugin that is expecting that format...  var item_source = data[i];  I thought about maybe working on the js side but can't get that far as I get a JSON.parse: unexpected character error when json is returned...saw it's expecting the above Goal format

Comment: In that case... I have updated my post with another option :)

Comment: Hey Oliver, thank you for sticking with me and the extra effort but I just tried your and that returns the same thing? Did you test it as maybe I'm missing something

Comment: I tested and got this:

["\/This\/That\/The other\/","\/This\/That\/The other\/","\/This\/That\/The other\/"]

I have also simplified the example.  Make sure that you are calling this method from the client and not within an actionresult, if you wrap an actionresult around this method, the javascript serialiser will re-convert the string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8548/discussion-between-bryant-and-oliver)